# How to make the file command use the magic file generated by update-mime-database command

Tags: file, compilation, mime-types

I am using Ubuntu Server 11.10.

My problem is that the `file` command detects files that should have had the `video/mp2t` mime-type as `application/octet-stream`

So here is what I did:

1. I made sure that `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml` contained the correct mp2t description.
2. I ran the `update-mime-database` command that, among other things, created a new magic file: `/usr/share/mime/magic`.
3. I discovered that when running `file -v`, it says that it is using `/etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic` as magic files.
4. So, I told the `file` command to use my new magic file: `file -m /usr/share/mime/magic MY_VIDEOFILE`

Here is where the problem starts. When running the `file` command with my new magic file, I get the following output:

```
/usr/share/mime/magic, 1: Warning: offset `MIME-Magic' invalid
/usr/share/mime/magic, 1: Warning: type `MIME-Magic' invalid
/usr/share/mime/magic, 2: Warning: offset `[90:application/docbook+xml]' invalid
/usr/share/mime/magic, 2: Warning: type `[90:application/docbook+xml]' invalid
  .
  . (921 lines removed from the output)
  .
/usr/share/mime/magic, 1173: Warning: offset `[10:text/x-tex]' invalid
/usr/share/mime/magic, 1173: Warning: type `[10:text/x-tex]' invalid
file: No current entry for continuation
```

It looks like the `file` command expects magic files in a different format than the format of the magic files that `update-mime-database` outputs.

What have I missed here?

How can I make the `file` command accept new mime types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the shared MIME type database seemed to be the wrong approach. In fact, it looks like the shared MIME database and the `file` command use seperate databases (with different formats).

The MIME type `video/mp2t` was not reported because of a too old version of the `file` command.

Ubuntu 11.10. comes with version 5.04 of the `file` command. This is unable to report the `video/mp2t` type.

This is what I did to solve the problem:

I downloaded a newer version of the [libmagic1 deb package](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libmagic1). This one has version 5.09-2.

I installed it:

```
sudo dpkg -i libmagic1_5.09-2_amd64.deb
```

Problem solved!

```
$ file MY_VIDEO_FILE --mime-type
MY_VIDEO_FILE: video/mp2t
```